# Amazon SageMaker notebook rl_deepracer_coach_robomaker - Write log CSV on S3 after simulation

Tags: amazon-s3, reinforcement-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I created my first notebook instance on Amazon SageMaker.
Next I opened the Jupyter notebook and I used the SageMaker Example in the section Reinforcement Learning `rl_deepracer_coach_robomaker.ipynb`. The question is addressed principally to those who are familiar with this notebook.

There you can launch a training process and a RoboMaker simulation application to start the learning process for an autonomous car.

When a simulation job is launched, one can access to the log file, which is visualised by default in a CloudWatch console. Some of the informations that appear in the log file can be modified in the script `deepracer_env.py` in `/src/robomaker/environments` subdirectory.

I would like to "bypass" the CloudWatch console, saving the log file informations like episode, total reward, number of steps, coordinates of the car, steering and throttle etc. in a dataframe or csv file to be written somewhere on the S3 at the end of the simulation.

Something similar has been done in the main notebook `rl_deepracer_coach_robomaker.ipynb` to plot the metrics for a training job, namely the training reward per episode. There one can see that

`csv_file_name = "worker_0.simple_rl_graph.main_level.main_level.agent_0.csv"`

is called from the S3, but I simply cannot find where this csv is generated to mimic the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a csv file in the `/opt/ml/output/intermediate/` folder, and the file will be saved in the following directory:

```
s3://<s3_bucket>/<s3_prefix>/output/intermediate/<csv_file_name>
```

However, it is not clear to me where exactly you will create such a file. DeepRacer notebook uses two machines, one for training (SageMaker instance) and one for simulations (RoboMaker instance). The above method will only work in a SageMaker instance, but much of what you would like to log such as ("Total rewards" in an episode) is actually in RoboMaker instance. For RoboMaker instances, the intermediate folder feature doesn't exist, and you'll have to save the file to s3 yourself using the boto library. Here is an example of doing that: https://qiita.com/hengsokvisal/items/329924dd9e3f65dd48e7

There is a way to download the CloudWatch logs to a file. This way you can just print, save the logs and parse it. Assuming you are executing from a notebook cell:

```
STREAM_NAME= <your stream name as given by RoboMaker CloudWatch logs>
task = !aws logs create-export-task --task-name "copy_deepracer_logs" --log-group-name "/aws/robomaker/SimulationJobs" --log-stream-name-prefix $STREAM_NAME --destination "<s3_bucket>" --destination-prefix "<s3_prefix>" --from <unix timestamp in milliseconds> --to <unix timestamp in milliseconds>
task_id = json.loads(''.join(task))['taskId']
```

The export is an asynchronous call, so give it a few minutes to download. If you can print the task_id, then the export is done.